# Proof Minimal Polynomial of $\left (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} \right ) ^{666}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, decimal-expansion, minimal-polynomials

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sqrt(2)%20%2B%20sqrt(3))%5E666) says it is:
$$ p:=X^2 -
\\34010363120518329895641913244818972821357722422049225139833901083899949664\\3109676116279151909642219515106579657522329002315790814575298372173755500\\4450204396353513751397454807621451130987201489527449320182179843543647401\\3457441914149811405514490266436995563308519019060191654063799652512313885\\722205521300795188376507318743522032330 \cdot X
 + 1$$

Obviously the degree cannot be any lower: Otherwise $z:=\left (\sqrt{2}  + \sqrt{3} \right )^{666} \in \mathbb {Z}$ .

However I have trouble proving that $p(z)=0$.

Here is what I tried so far:

There are $a_n \in \left \{ 0 \leq a <10 \space :\space a \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$$z=\sum_{n=-k}^{\infty}a_n \cdot 10^{-n} $$

Define:$$z_1:=\sum_{n=-k}^{0}a_n \cdot 10^{-n}$$
$$z_2:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cdot 10^{-n}$$

Coincidentally(?) the second coeffecient of p is exactly $-\left ( z_1+1\right )$:
$p(z)=p(z_1+z_2)=\left ( z_1+z_2 \right )^2-\left ( z_1+1 \right ) \left ( z_1+z_2 \right )+1=\left ( z_1+z_2 \right ) \left ( z_2 - 1 \right ) + 1= z\left (z_2-1 \right ) +1 =? $

Any ideas, why $\left (1-z_1 \right )$ could be the multiplicative inverse of z?

Am I on the right track at all?

Comment: $z\not\in\Bbb Z$...$z=a+b\sqrt6$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: Hint: $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2=5+\sqrt{6}\,$, then work out the recursion for $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{2n}=a_n + b_n \sqrt{6}\,$. The polynomial you are looking for will be $\,(x-a_{333}-b_{333}\sqrt{6})(x-a_{333}+b_{333}\sqrt{6})\,$.

Comment: So I might want to take a close look of $\mathbb{Q}\left ( \sqrt{6}\right )$? I noticed the binomial theorem earlier, but could not think of any way to take advantage of it back then.

Comment: +1 just for the exponent alone! Mwahahahahahahahahahahahaha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $a_n = (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^{2n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Because\begin{align*}
a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} &= (\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2})^{2n} + (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})^{2n}\\
&= (5 + 2\sqrt{6})^n + (5 - 2\sqrt{6})^n\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} 5^{n - k} (2\sqrt{6})^k + \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} 5^{n - k} (-2\sqrt{6})^k\\
&= 2 \sum_{\substack{0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\\k \ \text{even}}}\binom{n}{k} 5^{n - k} (2\sqrt{6})^k = 2 \sum_{0 \leqslant 2k \leqslant n} \binom{n}{2k} 5^{n - 2k} 24^k \in \mathbb{Z},
\end{align*}
then$$
a_n^2 - 2 \sum_{0 \leqslant 2k \leqslant n} \binom{n}{2k} 5^{n - 2k} 24^k \cdot a_n + 1 = 0.
$$
Since $a_n \notin \mathbb{Q}$, the minimal polynomial of $a_n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is$$
X^2 - 2 \sum_{0 \leqslant 2k \leqslant n} \binom{n}{2k} 5^{n - 2k} 24^k \cdot X + 1.
$$

Now, the question is the case where $n = 333$. Note that, by the definition of $z_1$, $z_1 = [a_n]$. Since $a_n > 1$ and $\displaystyle a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} \in \mathbb{Z}$, then$$
z_1 = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} - 1 \Longrightarrow -\left(a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}\right) = -(z_1 + 1).
$$

Comment: amazing could have thought about it

Comment: still it doesn't show, that the middle term is -(z_1+1) though, but thanks anyway the $5+2 \sqrt 6$ hint was much needed

Comment: @MartinErhardt I've added that part.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2=5+2\sqrt{6}.$ So we can write $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{333}$ as $a+b\sqrt{6}$ and the other root of the minimal polynomial will be $a-b\sqrt{6}$. You'll get that the product of the roots must be $1$ and the sum of the two roots must be $2a$. So the minimal polynomial will be: $x^2-2ax+1.$ 
Working out what $a$ will be is a bit tedious. You can actually write:

$$2a=\left\lceil \left(5+2\sqrt{6}\right)^{333}\right\rceil$$

Or you can use the method of [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to compute $(5+2\sqrt 6)^{333}$ somewhat efficiently. (Certainly more efficiently than the summation formula below, which is fairly expensive.)

Here's a python script which computes the value of $2a:$

```
def prod(v1,v2):
   # Compute (v1[0]+v1[1]sqrt(6))(v2[0]+v2[1]sqrt(6))
   return (v1[0]*v2[0]+6*v1[1]*v2[1],v1[0]*v2[1]+v1[1]*v2[0])

value = (1,0)
n = 333
a_2_to_k = (5,2)

while (n>0):
   if n%2==1:
       value = prod(value,a_2_to_k)
   n = n/2
   a_2_to_k = prod(a_2_to_k,a_2_to_k)

print 2*value[0]
```

with output:

$$
34010363120518329895641913244818972821357722422049\\
22513983390108389994966431096761162791519096422195\\
15106579657522329002315790814575298372173755500445\\
02043963535137513974548076214511309872014895274493\\
20182179843543647401345744191414981140551449026643\\
69955633085190190601916540637996525123138857222055\\
21300795188376507318743522032330$$

Comment: thanks but in fact I'm as well interested in this equation $2a=-(z_1+1)$ and the sum approach seems more fertile, than the recursive one in this context.

Comment: This is all amazing and more than asked for, but I should have mentioned, that I looked more towards a stick-and-paper-ish approach there

Comment: But I will probably figure this out myself tomorrow with the given hints.

Comment: This is still going to be easier to do by hand than the summation approach. This amounts to about $13$ multiplications of the form $(a+b\sqrt{6})(c+d\sqrt{6})$, which is going to be a lot easier than calculating $\binom{333}{k}$ for all $k$, not to mention $5^{n-2k}24^k$. Though I'd hate to do anything that computes a $332$-digit number by hand.

Comment: I would hate that as well :) ,but I have not planned to do so anyways: This was part of an exercise in which you had to determine the 42th decimal place of z without using any computers in the proof. Because of the equation $-(z_1+1)=2a$ I can develop a taylor series around z in such a way, that by insertion of z_1  $-10^{-43}<-10^{-330}<z-z_1<0$ follows, so that the 42th digit has to be nine.